# What to do when entities keeps changing in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm working on a chat-like application and would like to provide search capability for it. I was thinking of using Azure search. Once possibility is to consider each chat room as a single entity in the Azure search so that each entity represents a single chat room. The challenge I encounter is because each chat room keeps receiving new messages, the index for a chat room keeps changing. I can use a queue mechanism to queue up the changes and update my entities in the Azure Search but I don't know whether it is a good and scalable solution. Obviously I need to increase the number of replicas to keep up with the changes. Any recommendation? Is Azure search a suitable tool for such a scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H.Z.,

We do have customers that use us for Chat / Instant Message based applications, so we might be viable for your needs.  Before I answer your questions, can you tell me what types of things you would want to be able to search?

Is it merely to search the chat rooms or is it to search both chat rooms as well as the messages within these chat rooms?  If it is just to search the chat rooms, you might want to consider going your suggested approach and then store the chat messages in a lower cost store (such as Azure Storage) and then simply pull in the message text as needed.

If it is the latter, then the next question would be whether you want to be able to do a search that spans both chat rooms and the messages within them which would indicate that it makes a lot of sense to have them within a single index, although whether you put all messages in a single document or have one document per message we should drill into a bit more.  The main issue I would think of with having all messages in one index is in the case where a user wants to drill into (or filter) specific messages within a chat room.  I am thinking this might be a little harder then if you split messages into separate documents.

Another option might be to have 2 indexes.  One that has the chat rooms and then another that has the individual messages within them.

In any case, I hope that helps as a start and based on your responses hopefully I can help you drill into the details more.

Liam

Comment: Thanks @Liam for the elaborate answer. As a matter of fact, searching both char rooms and messages is the end goal. Let's first consider searching the chat rooms and keeping all the messages for a chat room in  a single entity. Because there will be many messages coming, the index for a single chat room should constantly get updated. Doesn't have a huge impact on the search service? Is the best way to implement it is to have a Service Bus kind of queue and then update the indexes for each single message using a worker role?

Comment: My other question is about the indexer? Can I still use an indexer and customized it such that it updates the indexes according to my need? Consider the scenario that a chat room title or members can also get updated.

Comment: Btw, I didn't quite get your recommendation of storing messages in Azure Table. o you mean to store the messages in a permanent storage and pull them to Azure search using a scheduled Indexer?

Comment: Hi H.Z., it may not be a good idea to store all messages in a chatroom in the same document, because 1) you wouldn't be able to capture per-message metadata, such as the sender, and 2) since there may be a large number of messages in the chatroom, you'll eventually hit practical document size limits. Storing each message as a separate document seems like a more flexible plan.

Comment: I completely agree with Eugene.  For your first question, adding content to the search service does have an impact on the overall service.  It is not that we throttle you, it is just that the Search Units you have, have a limited amount of resources which need to be shared by the data ingestion and the search queries.  Do you have an anticipated number of queries (searches )per second and updates (new messages) per second?  Please know that we can scale quite high and if needed can allocate larger search units.

Comment: For the updates, the main thing you should try to do (assuming you use the REST API to push content) is batch the updates as much as possible.  You can send up to 1000 documents in a single batch and you will find that this has a far lower impact then if you were to send them one by one.  Your queuing approach would likely work well.  It is possible to send only the changed fields (rather than the whole document).  We do this through an update called mergeOrUpload which will merge the fields with an existing document or insert one if it does not exist (http://bit.ly/1Npv6Gx).

Comment: For the indexer, yes we already use the mergeOrUpload method I mentioned above which means that if you change one or more fields in the source for the Indexer, these will be merged into the Azure Search index and the appropriate fields will be updated.  One thing to consider with the indexer is that it is a scheduled PULL rather than a PUSH as you would use with the API and will only run as often as every 5 minutes.  If you need to have the data searchable in a more real-time fashion, you might want to consider pushing the data directly into Azure Search.

Comment: For Azure Tables, I was referring to something different, and is not appropriate since you said you want to search the messages.  If you just wanted to search just the chat rooms.  What you could do is load in all the chat rooms into an Azure Search index and each document has a unique identifier. Then you also store the messages in something like Azure Tables.  Whenever someone searches the Chat Rooms, Azure Search will bring back the results and then using the unique identifier of that Chat Room, you then make another call to Azure Tables to bring back all the messages for that Chat Room.

Comment: This is a common technique when data does not need to be searchable.  For example, perhaps you have videos where you use Azure Search to index the metadata of the videos, yet store the actual video binaries in Azure Blob and simply load them as needed.

Comment: @EugeneShvets-MSFT: I didn't see anything about the limit on the document size on the 'limit page' of the Azure Search. Is there any? If so, what is that limit?

Comment: @LiamCavanagh-MSFT: Let's assume I go with the first approach and consider one single document for each chat room and want to use the PULL-based indexer. Is there any way to customized the indexer so it append the messages and not replace old ones with the new ones? I mean, the value of one field keeps getting appended.

Comment: Hi H.Z., there's an API request size limit of 16 MB, so you cannot have a single document larger than that in size. Also, it's not possible to append to the content of a field - it's possible to merge new fields into the document, or to replace the value of a field, but you cannot merge within a field.

Comment: @EugeneShvets-MSFT wouldn't that mean that you could update single fields with 16MB data, effectively having a document size equal to 16MB times number of fields?

Comment: @Peter, yes, hypothetically it could work, but then you won't be able to retrieve all the fields of a document when querying. I wouldn't recommend this strategy. Better to simply insert multiple documents that are somehow correlated.